# Find the all positive integer solutions $(a,b)$ to $\frac{a^3+b^3}{ab+4}=2020$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, divisibility, diophantine-equations

> Find the all positive integer solutions of given equation
>   $$\frac{a^3+b^3}{ab+4}=2020.$$

I find two possible solutions, namely $(1011,1009)$ and $(1009,1011)$, but the way I solve  the equation was messy and I don't know if there are any other solutions.

Source: Turkey $1.$ TST for IMO $2020$

Comment: This isn't Diophantine, by the way. Can you edit in your efforts?

Comment: my mistake sorry

Comment: Try to prove that $101\mid a+b$,  (otherwise $101\mid a^2-ab+b^2$ which is possible only if both $a$ and $b$ is divisible by $101$). Similarly, $5\mid a+b$, so we can bound $a^2-ab+b^2$.

Comment: I think the tag [tag:diophantine-equations] was fine, so I put it back in. This is, after all, a polynomial equation after the obvious manouver. But, it looks like it is from a contest in this year. I recommend that you provide a link to the contest page, or some other proof confirming that **the contest is over**. We have many users who take the integrity of math contests seriously, and have voted in a rule not to discuss questions from live contests. I don't suspect you would do such a thing, but some others have tried to cheat in the past.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I really did not know it was a contest questions  therefore  I can not provide a related link sorry

Comment: Appearance of an obvious calendar year is a tell-tale sign. No worries. @Aqua seems to have found the source.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha has [a graph and a solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+over+integers+%5Cfrac%7Ba%5E3%2Bb%5E3%7D%7Bab%2B4%7D-2020%3D0+). Somehow, it makes me think of the formula for generating all Pythagorean triples where $C-A=2$, i.e. $$A=4n^2-1\quad B=4n\quad C=4n^2+1$$

Answer (score 6):

Write for ease $n=2020$ and let $c=a+b$. As $b=c-a$ we get a following quadrtatic equation on $a$:  $$(3c+n)a^2-(3c+nc)a+c^3-4n=0$$
So it discriminat must be a perfect square $d^2$ (as it has solution in $\mathbb{Z}$):

$$d^2 = -3c^4+2nc^3+n^2c^2+48nc+16n^2\;\;\;\;\;(*)$$ from here we get $$\boxed{2n\mid d^2+3c^4}$$

Now what can we say about $c$?

- If $5\nmid c$ then $c^4\equiv_5 1$ so $d^2+3\equiv _5 0$ which is not possible. So $5\mid c$.
- Since $8\mid d^2+3c^2$, $d$ and $c$ nust be the same parity. Say both are odd. Since for each odd $x$ we have $x^2\equiv_8 1$ we get $$ 0\equiv _8 d^2+3c^4 \equiv_8 1+3$$ A contradiction. So $c$ and $d$ are even. Since $8\mid 3c^4$ we have $8\mid d^2$ so $4\mid d$.
- If $101\nmid c$ then $$d^2c^{-4} \equiv_{101} -3\implies \Big({-3\over 101}\Big)=1$$
  But $$\Big({-3\over 101}\Big) = \Big({-1\over 101}\Big)\Big({3\over 101}\Big) = 1\cdot \Big({101\over 3}\Big)(-1)^{{3-1\over 2}{101-1\over 2}} = -1$$
  A contradiction again, so $101\mid c$

So $$\boxed{1010\mid c}$$

Now suppose $c>n$. From $(*)$ we get:  \begin{align}3c^4&\leq 2nc^3+n^2c^2+48nc+16n^2\\
&< 2(c-1)c^3+(c-1)c^2+64c^2\\
& = 3c^4-4c^4+65c^2
\end{align}
and now we have $4c^3<65c^2$, a contradiction. So $c\leq 2020$.

So $c\in\{1010,2020\}$ and we check both values manualy...

Answer (score 5):

Note that if $p\mid a^2-ab+b^2$, where $p$ is a prime natural number s.t. $p\equiv 2\pmod{3}$, then $p\mid a$ and $p\mid b$.  For $p=2$, the claim is easily seen by inspection.  Let now $p>2$.  We prove by contradiction.  Suppose that $p\nmid a$ or $p\nmid b$.  It follows immediately that $p\nmid a$ and $p\nmid b$. Since
$$4(a^2-ab+b^2)=(2a-b)^2+3b^2\equiv0 \pmod{p},$$
we have $x^2\equiv-3\pmod{p}$, where $x=(2a-b)c$ if $c$ is an inverse of $b$ modulo $p$.  Consequently,
$$\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)=1.$$
By quadratic reciprocity,
$$\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)=\left(\frac{p}{-3}\right)=1.$$
Hence $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, which is a contradiction.

From $\frac{a^3+b^3}{ab+4}=2020$, we get
$$2020(ab+4)=a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2).$$
If $101\mid a^2-ab+b^2$, then $101\mid a$ and $101\mid b$ by the paragraph above.  Thus $101^3\mid (a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$, but clearly $101^3\nmid 2020(ab+4)$.  Hence, $101\mid a+b$.
Similarly, $5\mid a+b$.

If $2\mid a^2-ab+b^2$, then $2\mid a$ and $2\mid b$.  Write $a=2u$ and $b=2v$, then
$$1010(uv+1)=(u+v)(u^2-uv+v^2).$$
If $2\mid u^2-uv+v^2$, then $2\mid u$ and $2\mid v$.  Therefore $8\mid (u+v)(u^2-uv+v^2)$, but clearly $8\nmid 1010(uv+1)$.  Hence $2\mid u+v$.  Consequently $4\mid a+b$.  On the other hand, if $2\nmid a^2-ab+b^2$, then $4\mid a+b$ as $4\mid 2020$.  In any case, $4\mid a+b$.  This means $$a+b=4\cdot 5\cdot 101 \cdot k=2020 k$$ for some positive integer $k$.

Hence
$$k=\frac{a+b}{2020}=\frac{ab+4}{a^2-ab+b^2}.$$
Clearly $a\ne b$.  Since $a+b=2020k$, $a\equiv b\pmod{2}$ so $(a-b)^2\ge 4$.  If $(a-b)^2>4$, then $a^2-2ab+b^2>4$, making $ab+4<a^2-ab+b^2$, so
$$k=\frac{ab+4}{a^2-ab+b^2}<1,$$
which is a contradiction.  Hence, $(a-b)^2=4$, so that $ab+4=a^2-ab+b^2$, making $k=1$.  Thus we have $a+b=2020k=2020$ and $a-b=\pm\sqrt4=\pm2$.  This gives 
$$(a,b)=(1009,1011)\vee (a,b)=(1011,1009),$$
and both are solutions.  In fact, these two solutions are the only integer solutions (positive or negative) to the required equation.

Comment: Can you explain that part a little?How (-3/p)=1 implies (p/3)=(p/-3)=1.Sorry for my incompetence.